# java sql server dbcc SHRINKDATABASE

Tags: java, sql-server

How to execute `dbcc SHRINKDATABASE`  in java with sql server 2014.

Is it a callable, Statement or a PreparedStatement.

Or it should be executed as some command line command.

Comment: `Statement.execute("dbcc ....")` should work

Comment: Shall I use executeQuery to get output text from it?